# In App Purchases Apple: Donation/support developer with consumables products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I’m a mobile app developer and I’m currently fighting with Apple to get my binary that contains "In App Purchases" validated.
Apple keeps rejecting my binary because it wants me to change my products for donations/support into non-consumables because: by making a donation, the user also deletes the ads...

This is what I get everytime:

> Guideline 3.1.1 - Payments - Payments - In-App Purchase
>
> We still noticed that your in-app purchase product is set to an
> incorrect product type. remove_ads_1_reload, remove_ads_2_reload, and
> remove_ads_3_reload is set to Consumable. Next Steps Based on product
> functionality, please use the non-consumable in-app purchase product
> type. Non-consumable products are only purchased once by users and are
> always available on all devices that are associated with that user's
> App Store account. Note: The product type cannot be changed once an
> in-app purchase product has been created. Therefore, you will need to
> create a new in-app purchase product with the correct product type. To
> create new in-app purchases:
>
> - Log in to App Store Connect
> - Click on "My Apps"
> - Select your app
> - Click on "Features" to create new in-app purchases
> - Click Save
> - Once you've completed all changes, click the "Submit for Review" button at the top of the App Version Information page.

But I don't want to change these products to non-consumables, I want to leave the choice to the users to make a donation several times...
I'm tried to explain this to Apple, but no answers.

[This is my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhXxC.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow. I assume Apple reads your page as "paying removes the ads" and by enforcing you to use non-consumable, they want to ensure donors can use your app ad-free on all of their devices. Maybe you should remove the "Remove ads" part from the headline and state somewhere that supporters also get the app ad-free.

Another possibility would be to use non-renewing subscriptions (not intended for that usage, so maybe Apple doesn't like this either). Those can be bought multiple times and are synced over all devices of the user.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser! I called Apple to analyze my situation. I’ll come back here when I have an answer.

Comment: Ok so... Apple accepted my application after I appealed. All's well That ends well!

Comment: Good to hear. So they allow you to implement them as consumables?